# C++ Multidimensional Array Help: Iterate through to find user input & return if found it's other attributes

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

So I am extremely new to C++. I am not sure exactly what I am doing wrong. I have 6 items with 3 values each. A name, a customer id, and a number of punches. Essentially I want to be able to iterate through customer input to ensure that the ID they entered matches items in the second column and then return a string with the item to the left (name) and the value on the right (number of punches).

```
int main()
{

 string, double, int customerids[6][3] = {
    {"Trenton", 1234, 4},
    {"Joseph", 1235, 1},
    {"Kaldr", 1236, 0},
    {"Koda", 1237, 9},
    {"Kai", 1238, 5},
    {"Nova", 1239, 0}
    };


for (int i = 0; i < 6;  i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

        cout << "Please enter customer ID: ";
        cin >> customerinput;
        if (customerinput == customerids[i][j]);
                cout << "Thank you " customerids[i][j - 1] << " you have " customerids[i][j + 1] << "free punches" << endl;
    }   
  }

}
```

Comment: You should search in your C++ book for `struct`. I believe to know what you intended to achieve with `string, double, int customerids[6][3]` but that's not how C++ is working.

Comment: There are so many syntax errors and misunderstandings in your code that it is difficult to know where to begin addressing them. I *could* post a working version of what I presume you want (as could many other members of the Stack Overflow Community),  but I'm not sure that would be particularly helpful. Maybe you need to start learning C++ from a good book or other source?

Comment: Maybe start with leaning about the `struct` type (which is what your customer data should be based on)...

Comment: Thank you all! I will definitely look into the struct type in my course book. I initially asked my instructor for help and he left me more confused than when I started. He also had advised me to compare the input in the for loop. The extra semicolons were from the suggestions that VS continued to give me. I had watched and read way too much on arrays which also led me deeper down a rabbit hole of things that I did not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You should use a structure to group some values.
- You should remove the extra `;` from the `if` and `for` lines.
- You should use `>>` operator instead of `<<` with `cin`.
- You should declare the variable `customerinput`.
- You will need `<<` opetator between the strings and data to print.
- It looks like the loop with `j` is not needed and harmful because out-of-range access will happen, so the loop should be removed.

Fixed code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int main()
{

    struct { // use a structure
        string name;
        double customer_id;
        int number_of_punches;
    } customerids[6] = {
        {"Trenton", 1234, 4},
        {"Joseph", 1235, 1},
        {"Kaldr", 1236, 0},
        {"Koda", 1237, 9},
        {"Kai", 1238, 5},
        {"Nova", 1239, 0}
    };


    for (int i = 0; i < 6;  i++) { // remove the extra semicolon
        // remove the extra loop
        double customerinput; // declare the variable to use

        cout << "Please enter customer ID: ";
        cin >> customerinput; // use >> opetator
        if (customerinput == customerids[i].customer_id) // remove the extra semicolon
             cout << "Thank you " << customerids[i].name << " you have " << customerids[i].number_of_punches << "free punches" << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: Not sure this code will help the OP understand ... do you *really* think the `cin >> customerinput; ` line should be *inside* the `for` loop?

Comment: @AdrianMole No, I don't think it should be inside `for` loop. I am also doughtful whether `double` is a proper type for customer ID.